# No EVENT named markup://MYEVENTTYPE found : [markup://c:Component1, markup://c:Component2]

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I've created a couple of lightning components as well as a custom lightning event which is used in both components to talk to each other. The markup is as follows:

**Lightning Event (Name : MYEVENTTYPE)**

`<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Event template" />`

**Component 1 (markup):**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="FirstComponent">
    <aura:attribute name="showFirstComponent" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRecordId" type="String" default="" />     
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showFirstComponent == true}">
        <!-- First Component Body -->
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <span>
                <NS:SecondComponent recordId="{!v.selectedRecordId}" MYEVENT="{!c.EventFiredHandler}" />
            </span>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**Component 1 (controller):**

```
EventFiredHandler : function(component, event, helper) 
{
    // some code here
}
```

**Component 2 (markup):**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="SecondComponent">
    <aura:registerEvent name="MYEVENT" type="MYEVENTTYPE"/>
    <!-- the rest of the body for the component which fires off the function in the controller "someFunction" -->
</aura:component>
```

**Component 2 (controller):**

```
({
    someFunction : function(component, event, helper) {
        var cmpEvent = component.getEvent("MYEVENT");
        cmpEvent.fire();
    },
})
```

All of the above bundles are included in an unmanaged package (**Component 1, Component 2 and MYEVENT**), which uploads successfully. However, when I try to install the package into another org (Summer '15 Sandbox with enabled lightning components), I get the aforementioned error.

Has anyone experiences such a problem before? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I was missing the namespace when registering the event:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="MYEVENT" type="MYEVENTTYPE"/>
```

Should be:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="MYEVENT" type="NS:MYEVENTTYPE"/>
```